# XFS metadata I/O error

Tags: lvm, opensuse, xfs

Something odd for a couple of days. I've just noticed a lot of error messages in dmesg.

```
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=4118263528, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0xf577b6e0 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=727907056, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0x2b62fae8 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
[11:34:02 2020] attempt to access beyond end of device
[11:34:02 2020] dm-5: rw=32, want=727907056, limit=102432768
[11:34:02 2020] XFS (dm-5): metadata I/O error: block 0x2b62fae8 ("xfs_trans_read_buf_map") error 5 numblks 8
```

I am running on a **openSUSE 13.1** with Kernel **3.11.6-4-default**

The time that the dmesg report corresponds When the backup script starts.
This is a backup process: using lvm to snapshot the partition and then, I create a *tar.gz* into a share NFS.

```
lvcreate -L50000M -s -n backup_part /dev/server/DATA
mount -o nouuid,ro /dev/server/DATA /DATAbackup
umount /DATAbackup
lvremove -f /dev/server/DATA
```

dm-5 corresponds to the new lvm volume created for the snapshot and as soon the script complete. the mount is umounted and partition deleted.

```
# ls -al /dev/server/DATA
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1 Aug 31 14:05 /dev/server/DATA -> ../dm-5
```

The controller (raid5 hardware - MegaCli64) Does not report any issue, Whether it is disks or volume. They are all HEALTHY.

I may have to launch *xfs_repair*. But I wanted to know more about the errors.

It could be that the main original partition */dev/server/DATA* that I use to snapshot is corrupted?